# App name changed so redirect to new one in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web

We have a java web application running on tomcat with name, for example, abc/index.jsp

It is now changed to xyz/index.jsp

How can I redirect to the new url (xyz/index.jsp) when someone requesting with (abc/index.jsp)?

I want to set something within the tomcat (server.xml, web.xml, etc.) to redirect to the new url.

(I don't want to write code within the JSP to do that)

Could anybody please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache in the front, look at mod_proxy. Following should do.

```
ProxyPass /abc /xyz
```

Remember to enable the mod_proxy